# Return a recordset as HTML for Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g

I have an Oracle database and need to send out email notificaitons based on events that happen in my Dot Net web Application. The email notifications are in HTML format.  I have different templates that are used depending on the email notification that is to be generated. Each is connected to a Sproc. So when the event is called I pass an Id to handler and it calls a sproc. I then get the email template which is in HTML format and has Tags that are to be replaced with the fields from the sproc. I then search and replace any tags in the template with the corresponding field from the record set. The email recipeint is put in and the email sent as HTML format. This all works fine.

However I now have a requirement to show multiple rows in a table on an email notification. So for example, the details of books over from a library. I could get all the rows and build the HTML table rows on the fly in dot net by iterating over the record set and generating a new row for each record set but his would break my common approach of tag replacement.
So I would like to know can I build these multiple rows in  PL SQL and return it as one field where I can replace a tag in my html email template with the contents of a field from a record set. This field would contain the HTML version of all the required records... ready to ready as a table. So I would have a tag in my template called OVerDueBooks and replace that tag with the Field Over_Due_Books from my record set. This field would have all the over due book records in html format so I only have to replace the tag with the contents.

thanks Mick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gary,

I got this little gem from Sliqhtwv on EE and its works a treat. Thanks for your help.. much apprieciated.

**From Sliqhtwv:**

```
drop table tab1 purge;
create table tab1(col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1));

insert into tab1 values('a','1','A');
insert into tab1 values('b','2','B');
insert into tab1 values('c','2','C');
commit;

select xmlagg(xmlelement("TR",
    xmlforest(col1 as "TD",col2 as "TD",col3 as "TD"))).getclobval()
from tab1
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the data volume ? As long as the collected length isn't larger than 4000 bytes, it shouldn't be hard.

Search for STRAGG for various mechanism to aggregate a collection of VARCHAR2 into a single row.

The rest should jsut be a matter of `SELECT '<tr>'||....||'</tr>' ....`

Look into UTL_URL.ESCAPE to tidy away any characters that might interfere with the HTML.

Comment: thanks Gary.. I will have a look. I was looking to see was there some sort of HTML version to the dbms_xmlgen which generates the XML version or is it as you suggested and has to be hand carved in the sproc